# Programmaticaly setting color of a buttons border in iOs7

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am using this code to give my UIButtons a border (in iOs 7). It works reasonably well but only for one button state.

```
- (void)setRoundedBorder:(float) radius borderWidth:(float)borderWidth color:(UIColor*)color
{
    CALayer * l = [self layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:radius];
    // You can even add a border
    [l setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
    [l setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];
}
```

How can I adapt it so I can set a color for the button in selected/highlighted state. 
PS: Edited to add: This code (above) is inside of a category on UIButton.

I tried this:

```
    CALayer * l = [self layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:radius];
    // You can even add a border
    [l setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
    if (self.state == UIControlStateHighlighted) {
        [l setBorderColor:[anotherColor] CGColor]
    } else {
    [l setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];
}
```

This doesn't work as this is inside a category and apperently this can't detect the state change...

Comment: You could observe the button state and change the border color when it changes to selected and highlighted.

Comment: Which class is your `-setRoundedBorder:borderWidth:color:` declared in? Are you subclassing `UIButton`? Because the same code, applied to an `UIButton`'s layer, works in all the states for me.

Comment: It's inside of a category on UIButton.

Comment: I think there is reasoning behind apple deprecating the rounded rect buttons and making system buttons borderless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)setRoundedBorder:(float) radius borderWidth:(float)borderWidth color:(UIColor*)color state:(UIControlState*)buttonState
{

    CALayer * l = [self layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:radius];
    // You can even add a border
    [l setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
    [l setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];

    if(buttonState == UIControlStateHighlighted)
       [l setBorderColor:[YOURCOLOR CGColor]];

}
```

or

If this is your UIButton declaration then add selectors Like this,

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(highlightButtonBorder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(unhighlightButtonBorder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//Add extra selectors for other states if required as shown above 


- (void)highlightButtonBorder:(UIButton*)sender
{
    //your extra code goes here
    yourButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor YOURCOLOR]CGColor];
}

- (void)unhighlightButtonBorder:(UIButton*)sender
{
   //your extra code goes here
   myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor YOURCOLOR]CGColor];
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: doesn't work ... it doesn't detect that the state was changed or it can't set the color for the specific state

Comment: Can you post more code. I wanna see how its getting called. I'll edit my answer to give ya a alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the button itself as target for the `UIControlEvents`. This should work inside your category, just call `setupButton` once for the buttons.

```
- (void)setupButton{
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [self makeNormalState:self];

    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(makeHighlightedState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(makeNormalState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(makeNormalState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
}

- (void)makeNormalState:(UIButton*)sender{
    sender.layer.borderColor = normalStateColor.CGColor;
}

- (void) makeHighlightedState:(UIButton*)sender{
    sender.layer.borderColor = highlightedStateColor.CGColor;
}
```